# DNS Resolution with 2 upper server

Tags: networking, dns

My company is international and has subsidiary in China, and is using Google Apps for email, calendar, contacts, etc.

But unfortunately, we know Chinese Greater Firewall blocked google (and many others like Facebook, Twitter, etc.).

We have the VPN link to Singapore office, therefore I configure the local DHCP to allocate a DNS server in Singapore, so that will get the correct google servers' IP. And the traffic to google will go through Singapore and access google successfully. (We use Singapore DNS because sometimes China GFW do DNS poisoning, therefore can't trust the local China DNS provider)

But we don't want to route all traffic to Singapore, so I also setup traffic split route rule:

- All traffic dest to China IP range, will go directly through local Internet connection.
- All traffic dest to Non-China IP, will go through the VPN tunnel to Singapore.

This solution works fine until recently I find out that the Singapore server will resolve some China website (e.g. baidu.com, taobao.com, jd.com, etc.) to a IP which is located outside of China (e.g. IP in Hong Kong, IP in US, etc.) I guess it resolve to some mirroring host, or CDN host etc. Therefore all the web browsing traffic will go through Singapore.

This outside IP still works but the speed is quite slow compare to access these website with local DNS/Internet link (this make sense since the route will be much longer compare to local dest IP).

So my question is is there good practice to solve this issue?

My idea is to do selective DNS resolution on my local DNS server:

- Setup local DNS server with local DNS provider to resolve all DNS request, except:
- Add some DNS entry list (e.g. *.google.com, *.facebook.com) in local server, and setup a secondary DNS provider in Singapore.
- Whenever a client try to resolve *.google.com, local DNS server will notice and pass the request to the Singapore DNS provider, therefore bypass the China GFW DNS poisoning and get correct dest IP.

Could anyone recommend how to do it? Or recommend a better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is "conditional forwarding" which I've seen in SimpleDNS... http://www.simpledns.com/help/v50/index.html?df_forward.htm

Apparently, this is also available in the Windows DNS service... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794735(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks and will try and let community know the result.